# Failed to send mail via php, must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send a local mail but it always generates this error: `Must issue a STARTTLS command first.` I tried to find solution and I found this website which show [how to configure PHP under windows to use gmail or external STMP server](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/application-guides/544-configuring-php-under-windows-use-gmail-external-smtp-server-ssl.html) and I followed each step but it always generates the same error. I lost my way!!

Is there anyone who had encounter this problem before?
I'm gratefull for your help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, it sounds like the mail server that you are trying to send this message through is requiring STARTTLS on the connection.  STARTTLS is a type off connection that initially starts of unencrypted, then switches to an encrypted mode during the connection.  If your PHP script that is sending the message does not support STARTTLS, and the mail server that you are trying to send the message through requires STARTTLS, then you will get this error.

To solve the problem, you can do one of the following:

1)  Program your PHP script to connect to the mail server using a STARTTLS type of connection.  I'm not sure if you are using PHPMailer, but if you are, PHPMailer supports STARTTLS (set the SMTPSecure property to 'tls').

2)  Check if the mail server that you are trying to send through allows a different type connection (e.g. plaintext or SSL) on a different port.  If so, you can change your PHP script to connect using that type of connection on that port.

Comment: I don't use PHPMailer, just a simple php script. Indeed, i need to use phpMailer?

Comment: You might want to take a look at phpmailer.  It's is easy to use and simple to setup - just a few PHP files to copy to your server. See https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.  It's also very flexible - you can use to relay messages through a remote SMTP server on any port using any type of connection (e.g. plaintext, tls, ssl), and it also makes it simple to send more complicated types of MIME messages with attachments, HTML formatting, etc.

Comment: And if I won't use it, I want to create my own script, is thre a solution to do that?...You know, i use gmail server, smtp.gmail.com because I want to send a local mail via php

Comment: In that case, your PHP script must connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 587 using STARTTLS, or port 465 using SSL, and it must be capable of doing SMTP authentication using your gmail username and password.  See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en.

Comment: I use these configuration but i always have the same warning! Maybe, there is no solution for that kind of problem

Comment: OK, so you're simply using php's built-in mail() function.  This function (by default) will simply try to send the message out using the local MTA running on the server (usually by way of /usr/sbin/sendmail), unless you have some special configuration such that messages sent by way of the mail() function are relayed through a remote SMTP server.  Do you have something setup on this server that relays outgoing messages through smtp.gmail.com?  If so, can you post some info about your config?

Comment: I just setup sendmail.ini...That's all

Comment: OK, I think I see what your problem is.  Looking at the article that you referenced above about using 'fake sendmail' with PHP to relay outgoing mail through a remote SMTP host, it looks like 'fake sendmail' only supports plaintext connections to the remote host.  Back in 2008 when this article was written, smtp.gmail.com allowed plaintext connections, but it no longer does.  Because of this, I don't think 'fake sendmail' will work with smtp.gmail.com now - as I don't see a way in the sendmail.ini file to specify STARTTLS or SSL types of connections.

Comment: Actually, if you scroll down through the comments after the article, you'll see some comments where various posters got 'fake sendmail' to work with smtp.gmail.com since they started requiring STARTTLS and SSL, by using stunnel.  But, I think you might find it easier to simply use phpmailer...

Comment: I use phpmailer...And it run

Comment: $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; did it for me

Answer (score 0):

to connect to gmail, nowadays you need to get an "app password".

You must have 2-factor authentication to get an app password, which will have 16 characters.

So first, turn on 2-factor authentication: Click on your gmail icon; click 'Security'; underneath 'How you sign in to Google', enable 2 factor authentication.

Second, in the 'Security' screen, click into '2-factor authentication'; go to the very bottom of the screen and you'll see a menu for 'app passwords' where you can create a password for php mailer.